# Resigning - should I tell coworkers or let the boss do that?

Tags: resignation

I tendered my resignation, but management is not telling anyone so I am doing the same. I would like to tell coworkers but at the same time would like to give management the opportunity to deal with it the best way they see fit.

So - should I keep myself quiet and wait for them to inform the team?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> should I keep myself quiet and wait for them to inform the team?

Whenever I resign from a job, I always tell my boss first.

Then I ask if he or she will be telling others, and when. Since I am in management, I always request the courtesy of telling my team directly - that has always been granted.

Often, I am asked to wait a few days while my boss notifies others in the management chain, and occasionally tries to convince me to stay. I always agree to wait a few days, although I don't accept a counter-offer.

Within a few days I start telling others, if they haven't heard already.

In short, talk with you boss and arrange a time in the near future so that everyone will know about your departure one way or the other.

Comment: I'm mid-typing and your answer pops up saying exactly what I was going to say.  lol, you're the Jon Skeet of Workplace.  :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Skeet is somewhat a celebrity - highest points in stack exchange history.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you certainly help and I appreciate it.

Comment: Plus, Jon is really quick on the answers.  I can't count how many times I'd be starting to type something and "whoop, there it is" his answer. And given that Jon is flipping brilliant his answers are always better than mine. lol (this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet )

Comment: You should consider writing a book capturing all your workplace wisdom (if you haven't done so already).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I thought everyone over 100k rep on any SE site was apart of Jon Skeet's secret parties!

Comment: NOTE to others:  I told my co-workers BEFORE I told my boss once.  PROBLEM SOLVED!  (won't help OP though)

Answer (score 4):

Ask your Boss when to tell. She/He may have reasons to resolve issues around you leaving in a quiet atmosphere i.e. asking specific other colleagues if they are willing/ready to take over some roles from you. Depending on your position, you can create significant confusion by telling early.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers are  on target when you're leaving a good team on good terms. But sometimes you aren't.

### An imperfect world

On two occasions I had to leave a company purely due to dysfunctional management. When submitting my resume, I knew the Director didn't understand how to communicate with the team and would just keep it quiet and hope for everything to blow over after I left.

In those situations, my relationship with my team and other departments was more important than anything else. In both cases, I gave the Director 24 hours and then started quietly communicating with others and putting plans for overall success in place. In both cases, the Director kept their head in the sand and didn't say a word until confronted several days later.

While my Director wasn't happy in either situation, the rest of the team was and I have maintained many of those relationships in the years since. In fact, in one of those scenarios, the SVP came to me and thanked me for taking the initiative to ensure success upon my departure. He even offered me a higher position away from the problem Director. I declined, but it was good reinforcement that I had done the right thing.